compatibility issue with ydlidarx2 ubuntu24.4
i am trying to make ydlidar x2 work with ubuntu 24.4 (ros jazzy)
i am getting cmake errors
  The source directory

    /home/pussycat/ydlidar_ws/src/YDLidar-SDK/src/core

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /home/pussycat/ydlidar_ws/src/YDLidar-SDK/src/examples

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /home/pussycat/ydlidar_ws/src/YDLidar-SDK/src/src

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

is it even compatible with 24.4 is there any way i can use lidar data without the ydlidar drivers ??

Their github page says if you encounter that error you should install the SDK as a separate step. Have you done that?

Yup I am getting cmake error which does not let drivers being installed
